# How to install Go package manually from source code

Tags: go, go-micro, goa

I'm living in China and is not able to download & install GO package through command (event I use the vpn network):

```
 go get -u <repo_url>
```

but I can access the **repo_url** and downloand its source code.
So my question is can I put the scource code under **src** folder and run commamd ? :

```
go install
```

if yes, what's the different betweeen the two way ?

Comment: Please have a look at the official documentation: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies

Comment: @MarcoTalento: You need to take into account the limits on internet access in China. Some of them are mentioned in the question. For China, https://golang.google.cn may be a better site: [The Go Blog: Hello, 中国!](https://blog.golang.org/hello-china).

Comment: What happens when you try the `go get`? Do you get an error, and if so, what is it?

Comment: @peterSO golang.google.cn is exactly what I need! THX!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

for example, you have the `repo_url` at https://github.com/hello/example

You can do `go get` manually by

```
$ cd $GOPATH
$ mkdir -p src/github.com/hello
$ cd src/github.com/hello
$ git clone https://github.com/hello/example.git
$ cd example
$ go install
```

the binary will install into `$GOPATH/bin`

if the go program of the repo_url depends on other go package. you have to manually get it and put it to correct path location too.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are important when one looks to get a required package manually,

1. Path to the package repository; for example, [github.com/golang/crypto.git](https://github.com/golang/crypto) package is hosted on Github. However, when using on code should import as [golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt](http://golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt)

   Google the required package
2. Path in the `$GOPATH`. In this example, the repository should be cloned inside `golang.org` directory and inside the appropriate directories. To me, the solution to find the path is running code and read the errors for missing modules/packages.